# How to click on element in android using appium when DOM is not loading?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I am automating a native android application using appium and java. I could find locators of each element. Please refer below screen shots for your reference. Its not working as expected and getting me time out exception i.e. failed to find element where you can see, I have given correct id. 
For time being, I am using touchaction with x,y co-ordinates which is not correct solution. please help me to solve it.

Code snippet:

[image]

For example :

[image]

Exception Screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking [`driver.getPageSource()` method](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource--) and double check that the desired element is present in the XML page representation.

Going forward you can set `printPageSourceOnFindFailure` to `true` so Appium would print the source code of the page to the [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) on element find failure like:

```
caps.setCapability("printPageSourceOnFindFailure", true);
```

More information:

- [Appium Desired Capabilities](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/)
- [Appium Studio for Eclipse - Capabilities Manager](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Appium+Studio+for+Eclipse+-+Capabilities+Manager)